# Property of Sylow subgroups on subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

We know that the following fact holds: If $G$ is finite group and $N$ is normal in $G$ and $P\in \text{Syl}_p(G)$ then $P\cap N\in \text{Syl}_p(N)$. Also converse is also true that if $Q\in \text{Syl}_p(N)$ then $Q=P\cap N$ where $P\in \text{Syl}_p(G)$.

But I was wondering what if we omit the condition of normality? Can we conclude that $P\cap N$ will be Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy counterexample is given by any Sylow subgroup that isn't normal. Its intersection with another Sylow subgroup is not a Sylow subgroup of itself.

Comment: Yes, indeed let's take $G=S_4$ and it has $3$ Sylow $2$-subgroups. None of them is normal but intersection of two is not $2$-Sylow in none of them because it's order $<2^3$. Right?

Comment: @RFZ That's right.